# Node position in XPath

Tags: xml, xpath

Suppose I got the following xml:

```
<avdc:DbDocument Version="14.1.0.4[E14104-11]" CreationTime="2015-06-09T10:44:47" xmlns:avdc="http://www.aveva.com/xml/DbDocument" xmlns:udet="http://www.aveva.com/xml/udet" xmlns:uda="http://www.aveva.com/xml/uda">
    <avdc:Project Name="SUR">
        <avdc:Mdb Name="ALL">
            <avdc:Database Type="9" TypeName="Engineering" Name="TAGSADMIN/DOCSREGI" Number="500" ExtractNumber="1" World="=8692/0" />
        </avdc:Mdb>
    </avdc:Project>
    <udet:ENGDOC TYPE="ENGITE" REF="=16884/3" ACTTYPE=":ENGDOC" OWNER="=16884/2" OWNERREF="=16884/2" NAME="" DESC="" SCSYSF="" uda:ENGDOCNO="2100-0012FM5280-112-0001" uda:ENGDOCREF="" uda:ENGDOCFILE="" uda:ENGDOCAREA="" uda:ENGDOCSUBAREA="" uda:ENGDOCDATEITB="2015-06-03T21:00:00Z" />
    <udet:ENGDOC TYPE="ENGITE" REF="=16884/4" ACTTYPE=":ENGDOC" OWNER="=16884/2" OWNERREF="=16884/23" NAME="" DESC="" SCSYSF="" uda:ENGDOCNO="2100-0012FM5280-112-0002" uda:ENGDOCREF="" uda:ENGDOCFILE="" uda:ENGDOCAREA="" uda:ENGDOCSUBAREA="" uda:ENGDOCDATEITB="2015-06-03T21:00:00Z" />
    <udet:ENGDOC TYPE="ENGITE" REF="=16884/5" ACTTYPE=":ENGDOC" OWNER="=16884/2" OWNERREF="=16884/23" NAME="" DESC="" SCSYSF="" uda:ENGDOCNO="2100-0012FM5280-112-0002" uda:ENGDOCREF="" uda:ENGDOCFILE="" uda:ENGDOCAREA="" uda:ENGDOCSUBAREA="" uda:ENGDOCDATEITB="2015-06-03T21:00:00Z" />
</avdc:DbDocument>
```

How can I exctract row numbers for each udet:ENGDOC elements?
Say **1** - for first, **2** - for second, etc.
I've tried to play around with position() function but this didn't help.

Many thanks!

Comment: In XQuery, you can use the keyword at

Comment: *"I've tried to play around with position() function but this didn't help."*. How did you try, and what happened? What was the output?

Comment: `position()` should work for your XML if you are iterating on every `udet:ENGDOC` and using it. Or, try using `count(preceding-sibling::udet:ENGDOC) + 1` to know the position of `udet:ENGDOC` in the current parent.

Comment: You can do this easily with position() or with xsl:number. Tell us what you did and tell us how it failed.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear but I'm a bit confused experimenting with XPath exercices [here](https://lagunita.stanford.edu/courses/DB/XPath/SelfPaced/courseware/ch-querying_xml/seq-exercise-xml_course_xpath_xquery_core/) Don't know why but expression like doc("courses.xml")//Course/position() works correct there